# How to wait for HTML to draw before javascript function runs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a webapp that involves adding and manipulating many html elements with javascript.

Here is an example of my problem:

function 1: change the text size of all 500 elements

function 2: scroll to element #350 based on the location of element 350 (pixels from top).

The problem is that sometimes it takes time for the css to redraw the elements at the new size, so when function 2 fires, it is not accurate and it will end up scrolling to the wrong place.

function 1 works by using jquery to change the content of the `<style></style>` element in the html head.

how can I make javascript wait for browser to finish drawing before firing without guessing with arbitrary timeouts?

Comment: You will need to provide actual samples of your code in order to get the assistance you desire.

Comment: in modern browsers can use mutationObeserver API

Answer (score 3):

You can make your jquery fire after the page has loaded by including your jquery functions inside of this:

```
$(function() {
    //your functions
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your script tags right at the bottom of your page. This ensure your DOM has been loaded and also allows the user to perceive the page as quickly as possible! Fantastic news, particularly if your scripts take a significant amount of time to execute as you can put a lovely loading graphic in there as a placeholder for top notch UX! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [window.addEventListener("load"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load) it  s pure javascript

```
function load () {
      alert("Window loaded");
}

window.addEventListener("load", load, false);
```